# HighCharts: How to give Gradient color to xAxis crosshair?

Tags: highcharts

I am using highchart in my project But i don't know how to give gradient color to x-axis crosshair

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a plot band using `Axis.addPlotBand()` function on `mouseOver` and remove it on `mouseOut` with `Axis.removePlotBand()`. To apply gradient, use `linearGradient` along with `stops`. Take a look at the example below.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.addPlotBand
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.removePlotBand

DOCS Reference:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/36comwzL/